# dynamically generate IN condition in pig

Tags: java, apache-pig

I'm using pig 0.12 version and i want to generate dynamic **IN** condition using a reference.

in my pig file i have 'm_master' relation and when i say `DESCRIBE m_master` it gives me the following

```
m_master: {m_id: chararray,m_name: chararray,in_dx: chararray,rolled_up_name: chararray,match_code: chararray,match0: chararray,flag_ind: chararray}
```

now i want to perform some operation like

```
UPDATE M_Master SET flag_ind='SE' WHERE Rolled_Up_Name IN (SELECT DISTINCT Rolled_Up_Name FROM M_Master WHERE flag_ind='SE') AND flag_ind='Non SE'
```

which is equal to RDBMS query.

i have generated distinct roll_up_names from m_master which is refered as distinct_rollup_names

```
m_master = FOREACH m_master GENERATE m_id, m_name, in_dx, rolled_up_name, match_code, match0, 
    (
        (
            flag_ind='Non SE' AND rolled_up_name IN (<b>distinct_rollup_names</b>)
        ) ? 'SE' : flag_ind
    ) as flag_ind;
```

how to use the generated relation values within IN condition, any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pig does not support IN clause as you are expecting. Self join m_master on rolled_up_name column and then update left side flag_ind to SE if its non SE and if right side flag_ind is SE

```
--Original m_master
m_master: {m_id: chararray,m_name: chararray,in_dx: chararray,rolled_up_name: chararray,match_code: chararray,match0: chararray,flag_ind: chararray}

-- Clone m_master into m_master2
m_master2 = FOREACH m_master GENERATE m_id, m_name, in_dx, rolled_up_name, match_code, match0, flag_ind;

-- We are interested only in SE flag_ind (this works as inner query in your question)
m_master2 = filter m_master2 by flag_ind == 'SE';

-- Now join m_master and m_master2
m_master_self_joined = JOIN m_master BY rolled_up_name LEFT OUTER, m_master2 BY rolled_up_name;

-- Now pick fields from m_master
-- When there is a match with m_master2, set flag_ind to SE
m_master_self_joined2 = FOREACH m_master_self_joined 
                        GENERATE 
                            m_master::m_id,
                            m_master::m_name,
                            m_master::in_dx,
                            m_master::rolled_up_name,
                            m_master::match_code,
                            m_master::match0,
                            (m_master::m_id == null ? 'Non SE' : 'SE');

-- Its possible to have duplicates (if rolled_up_name is not unique), so take uniques
m_master_self_joined3 = DISTINCT m_master_self_joined2;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: for your information PIG 0.12 supports IN, i have used it in some other scenarios

Comment: Thanks @PrasadKhode, I didnt know about IN support in 0.12 version.